# PyQt5 Retrieve Folder Directory and Set It in lineEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qfiledialog

Need some advice on how to retrieve the directory path for a selected folder and set it on the LineEdit.

I have the following simple GUI
[image]

If I clicked the toolButton (the button inside the red-circle), then a dialog window would pop up. Then we could navigate to select the desired folder. I wish that I could pass the path (in string) to the selected folder to the lineEdit box next to the button, once the user clicks Select Folder. However, I could not figure out how to do that. So far here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_TestQFileDialog(object):
    def _open_file_dialog(self): # a function to open the dialog window
        result = str(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
        print(result)
        return result

    def setupUi(self, TestQFileDialog):
        TestQFileDialog.setObjectName("TestQFileDialog")
        TestQFileDialog.resize(240, 320)

        self.toolButtonOpenDialog = QtWidgets.QToolButton(TestQFileDialog)
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 25, 19))
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setObjectName("toolButtonOpenDialog")
        directory = self.toolButtonOpenDialog.clicked.connect(self._open_file_dialog)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(TestQFileDialog)
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setText('{}'.format(directory))

        self.retranslateUi(TestQFileDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestQFileDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, TestQFileDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestQFileDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("TestQFileDialog", "Dialog"))
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setText(_translate("TestQFileDialog", "..."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    TestQFileDialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_TestQFileDialog()
    ui.setupUi(TestQFileDialog)
    TestQFileDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tried to include print in the _open_file_dialog function, and it printed the directory path. However, it was not returned and kept in the directory variable.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Arnold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer, the .setText method should be included in the _open_file_dialog function.

Therefore, the final code would look like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_TestQFileDialog(object):
    def _open_file_dialog(self):
        directory = str(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
        self.lineEdit.setText('{}'.format(directory))

    def _set_text(self, text):
        return text

    def setupUi(self, TestQFileDialog):
        TestQFileDialog.setObjectName("TestQFileDialog")
        TestQFileDialog.resize(240, 320)

        self.toolButtonOpenDialog = QtWidgets.QToolButton(TestQFileDialog)
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 25, 19))
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setObjectName("toolButtonOpenDialog")
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.clicked.connect(self._open_file_dialog)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(TestQFileDialog)
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(TestQFileDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestQFileDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, TestQFileDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestQFileDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("TestQFileDialog", "Dialog"))
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setText(_translate("TestQFileDialog", "..."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    TestQFileDialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_TestQFileDialog()
    ui.setupUi(TestQFileDialog)
    TestQFileDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

With QWidget

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFileDialog,QDialog,QToolButton,QLineEdit,QVBoxLayout ,QGridLayout

class Ui_TestQFileDialog(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None) -> None:
        super(Ui_TestQFileDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def _open_file_dialog(self,lineeditr):
        directory = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
        lineeditr.setText('{}'.format(directory))
    def _open_file_dialog1(self):
        directory = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory())
        self.lineEdit1.setText('{}'.format(directory))

    def _set_text(self, text):
        return text

    def setupUi(self):

        # ------------------------- first set  ------------------------------------------------------
        TestQFileDialog = QDialog()
        # TestQFileDialog.setObjectName("TestQFileDialog")
        # TestQFileDialog.resize(240, 320)

        self.toolButtonOpenDialog = QToolButton(TestQFileDialog)
        # self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 25, 19))
        # self.toolButtonOpenDialog.setObjectName("toolButtonOpenDialog")
        

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(TestQFileDialog)
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
        # self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 20))
        # self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.prine_la)
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog.clicked.connect(lambda: (self._open_file_dialog(self.lineEdit)))

        # ----------------------------- second set  --------------------------------------------------------
        TestQFileDialog1 = QDialog()
        # TestQFileDialog1.setObjectName("TestQFileDialog")
        # TestQFileDialog1.resize(240, 320)

        self.toolButtonOpenDialog1 = QToolButton(TestQFileDialog1)
        # self.toolButtonOpenDialog1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 25, 19))
        # self.toolButtonOpenDialog1.setObjectName("toolButtonOpenDialog")
        

        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit(TestQFileDialog1)
        self.lineEdit1.setEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit1.setPlaceholderText("Enter the gain value in between 0.0 to 23.05934920")
        # self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 20))
        # self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
        self.toolButtonOpenDialog1.clicked.connect(lambda: (self._open_file_dialog(self.lineEdit1)))


        self.retranslateUi(TestQFileDialog,self.toolButtonOpenDialog,"TestQFileDialog","data")
        self.retranslateUi(TestQFileDialog1,self.toolButtonOpenDialog1,"TestQFileDialog1","data1")
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestQFileDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TestQFileDialog1)


        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit,0,0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.toolButtonOpenDialog,0,1)

        grid_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1,1,0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.toolButtonOpenDialog1,1,1)

        ve_box= QVBoxLayout()
        # ve_box.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        # ve_box.addWidget(self.toolButtonOpenDialog)
        # ve_box.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        # ve_box.addWidget(self.toolButtonOpenDialog1)
        ve_box.addLayout(grid_layout)
        self.setLayout(ve_box)

    def prine_la(self):
        print(self.lineEdit.text())
    def retranslateUi(self, TestQFileDialog,tool,dialogue:str,d: str):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TestQFileDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate(dialogue, d))
        tool.setText(_translate(dialogue, "..."))
        print("ANR .S")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_TestQFileDialog()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```